# How to load nodes from sks file and then apply action defined in Scene Editor

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

I have two sks files, one with nodes and another with actions both created in Scene Editor. I want to load nodes and add them to another node and then apply actions to them, something like:

```
override func sceneDidLoad() {

    let heroScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "Hero")
    let head = heroScene?.childNode(withName: "HeroHead") as! SKSpriteNode
    let testAction = SKAction(named: "HeroTestAction") as! SKAction
    let loop = SKAction.repeatForever(testAction)
    let hero = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0) , size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 250))
    let body = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.blue, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))

    head.removeFromParent()
    hero.addChild(head)
    hero.addChild(body)
    self.addChild(hero)

    head.run(loop)
    body.run(loop)

}
```

But action does not apply to `head`. If i apply loop to `body` or `hero` it works.

What I do wrong? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Update: When I first time run example, action not works, but if close app and run again it is works.

[image]

Comment: Create a subclass of SKSpriteNode.

Comment: @ElTomato Should i use subclass for every node or particular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could want to say there is an interesting "feature" where when you grab a reference sprite like that it comes in as `isPaused = true;`

Try adding this

```
head.isPaused = false;
```

I believe I ran into a similar problem before when grabbing a sprite from another scene.

Comment: Yes, that's helps! Great Thanks!